# PDF/UA Accessibility in mPDF

Tags: accessibility, mpdf, wcag2.0

Is there a way to make the pdf tagged and add other pdf/ua functionality? If there is no direct way, is it possible to use some sort of raw write command to add the tags? We are generating pdf documents from HTML pages, on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo, but it should be PDF/UA in the title as well.  Don't think I can change that.

Comment: fixed the title for you. You can do that by clicking 'edit' and changing the title in the box above the main question section for future reference. I don't think you can do this with just HTML, you would normally convert HTML to PDF in the back-end and add tags there. However I am open to being corrected by someone!